# FullSimplify not yielding True for Log[a/b] == Log[a] - Log[b]?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am not receiving `True` for `Log[a/b]==Log[a]-Log[b]`. Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: Is this statement true always? What happens when b is complex, or b == 0?

Comment: @DrMrstheMonarch Oh good point! Is there a way to add conditions to FullSimplify?

Comment: Look up assumptions in the docs :)

Comment: @DrMrstheMonarch Thank you!

Comment: It is sufficient to use `Simplify`, e.g. `Simplify[Log[a/b] == Log[a] - Log[b], a != 0 && b > 0]`

Comment: `Log[a/b] == Log[a] - Log[b] // PowerExpand`

Comment: @Alan: This is a weakness/bug in `PowerExpand` and the documentation says it in a similar situation "Expand a power of a product; the result may not be correct everywhere:"

Comment: @user64494 It is a feature not a weakness or bug. But yes, care in use is required. In this case, it meets the demands of the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. One can use a standard Mma approach of working with logarithms. It is PowerExpand.

PowerExpand treats its expressions assuming all variables are positive. Normally

```
Log[ab] == Log[a] + Log[b]
```

is not always true, e.g.

```
0 = Log[(-1) (-1)] != Log[-1] + Log[-1] == 2 Pi*I
```

2. One can use Simplify together with the declaration of the variables  as positive (if it is true):

   ```
    Simplify[Log[a] + Log[b], Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0]

   (* Log[a b]  *)
   ```

   PowerExpand[Log[a*b], Assumptions -> a > 0 < b]

   ```
    (* Log[a] + Log[b]  *)
   ```

In general

```
PowerExpand[Log[a b], Assumptions -> Element[{a, b}, Complexes]]

  

(*  2 I \[Pi] Floor[1/2 - Arg[a]/(2 \[Pi]) - Arg[b]/(2 \[Pi])] + Log[a] + Log[b]  *)
```

3. If I know that the variables are positive, and want to transform logarithms I use the following functions:

expandLog[expr_] := Module[{rule1, rule2, a, b, x, g},
rule1 = Log[a_*b_] -> Log[a] + Log[b];
rule2 = Log[a_^x_] -> x*Log[a];
g[x_] := (x /. rule1) /. rule2;
FixedPoint[g, expr]
];

and

```
collectLog[expr_] := Module[{rule1a, rule1b, rule2, g, a, b, x},
       rule1a = Log[a_] + Log[b_] -> Log[a*b];
       rule1b = Log[a_] - Log[b_] -> Log[a/b];
       rule2 = x_*Log[a_] -> Log[a^x];
       g[x_] := x /. rule1a /. rule1b /. rule2;
       FixedPoint[g, expr]
       ];
```

They enable me to transform logarithms according to my wish. Try them.

Have fun!